# How to set the default tabbedpannel in adf?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have a page with a tabbedpanel with 2 item on on changing the selected item and reopening the page the last selected item is the selected tab. I want to set the first tab as the default tab how can i achieve this.

I have a JSFF page

```
<af:panelTabbed position="above" id="pt1" styleClass="AFStretchWidth" childCreation="lazy">
        <af:showDetailItem id="tab1"
                           text="tab1"
                           disclosed="#{pageFlowScope.expandHeader}" 
                           stretchChildren="first">
        </af:showDetailItem>
        <af:showDetailItem id="tab2"
                           text="tab2"
                           stretchChildren="first"
                           disclosed="#{pageFlowScope.expandLine}"
                           styleClass="AFStretchWidth">
        </af:showDetailItem>
</af:panelTabbed>
```

And a **Backing Bean**
How do i use these two so that when ever i open this page the first tab is opened by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the disclosed only changes what tab opens the first time you open the page. If you reopen it after changing the tab the last opened tabbed is shown. Changing childCreation also didnot help.

I added a `doneActionlistner` to the
`<fnd:simplePanel` and a binding to the `<af:panelTabbed`.
Now, from the bean i created a onDone action and also added a function to change the tab.

```
public void onDone(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    setTabActive(0);
    return ;
}
public void setTabActive(int tab) {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ChangeManager cm = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().getChangeManager();
        ComponentChange ccTrue = new AttributeComponentChange("disclosed", Boolean.TRUE);
        ComponentChange ccFalse = new AttributeComponentChange("disclosed", Boolean.FALSE);
        if (this.myPanelTab != null) {
            RichShowDetailItem activeTab = null;
            RichShowDetailItem inActiveTab = null;
            List<UIComponent> childUIComponent = this.myPanelTab.getComponent().getChildren();
            if (childUIComponent != null && childUIComponent.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < childUIComponent.size(); i++) {
                    if (childUIComponent.get(i) instanceof RichShowDetailItem) {
                        if (i == tab) {
                            activeTab = (RichShowDetailItem)childUIComponent.get(i);
                            activeTab.setDisclosed(true);
                            cm.addComponentChange(fc, activeTab, ccTrue);
                        } else {
                            inActiveTab = (RichShowDetailItem)childUIComponent.get(i);
                            inActiveTab.setDisclosed(false);
                            cm.addComponentChange(fc, inActiveTab, ccFalse);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(myPanelTab.getComponent());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the second showDetailItem of the panelTabbed disclosed, you need his disclosed attribute to be true and the other showDetailItem disclosed attribute to be false.

In your case, the boolean #{pageFlowScope.expandLine} need to be equal to TRUE and #{pageFlowScope.expandHeader} equal to FALSE

You can test it by simply putting the value true or false in the dislosed attribute.
For example, this would work :

```
<af:panelTabbed position="above" id="pt1" styleClass="AFStretchWidth" childCreation="lazy">
        <af:showDetailItem id="tab1"
                           text="tab1"
                           disclosed="false"
                           stretchChildren="first">
        </af:showDetailItem>
        <af:showDetailItem id="tab2"
                           text="tab2"
                           stretchChildren="first"
                           disclosed="true"
                           styleClass="AFStretchWidth">
        </af:showDetailItem>
</af:panelTabbed>
```

or event without disclosed="false" since disclosed default value is false :

```
<af:panelTabbed position="above" id="pt1" styleClass="AFStretchWidth" childCreation="lazy">
        <af:showDetailItem id="tab1"
                           text="tab1"
                           stretchChildren="first">
        </af:showDetailItem>
        <af:showDetailItem id="tab2"
                           text="tab2"
                           stretchChildren="first"
                           disclosed="true"
                           styleClass="AFStretchWidth">
        </af:showDetailItem>
</af:panelTabbed>
```

In those 2 example, the second showDetailItem will be disclosed when first displayed.

Comment: When the page first opens it is opening the desired tab but we select a new tab now and go back and revisit the page the last tab that i had selected gets opened.

Comment: Must be because of cache. Put the childCreation attribute of your panelTabbed to "lazyUncached"